# SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/bash from execute access on the file myfilename.sh in nginx via php-fpm

Tags: selinux

**Background:**
I have two CentOS7 servers.  `Test` & `Prod`.
There is a script `myfilename.sh` in my website, which is executed in php by `shell_exec`.
Script and all parent folders in both servers have identical selinux context. `httpd_sys_rw_content_t`

**Problem statement:**
Script runs fine in `Test` server but doesn't work on `Prod`.
Audit log on `Prod` says `SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/bash from execute access on the file myfilename.sh.`, but nothing shows up in `Test` box.

Any idea what could have possibly gone wrong and why the script is working on `Test` box. I need to reproduce the issue on `Test` server before fixing it on prod.

Here is the audit log:

```
SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/bash from execute access on the file myfilename.sh.

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that bash should be allowed execute access on the myfilename.sh file by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'sh' --raw | audit2allow -M my-sh
# semodule -i my-sh.pp


Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0
Target Context                unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0
Target Objects                myfilename.sh [ file ]
Source                        sh
Source Path                   /usr/bin/bash
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          <Unknown>
Source RPM Packages           bash-4.2.46-21.el7_3.x86_64
Target RPM Packages           
Policy RPM                    selinux-policy-3.13.1-102.el7_3.16.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Enforcing
Host Name                     ip-X-X-X-X
Platform                      Linux ip-X-X-X-X 3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64
                              #1 SMP Tue Feb 16 17:03:50 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   23
First Seen                    2017-06-17 06:33:36 CDT
Last Seen                     2017-06-18 02:18:01 CDT
Local ID                      340158ca-61f6-4472-aadb-18a3bbc34a22

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1497770281.465:12508): avc:  denied  { execute } for  pid=10042 comm="sh" name="myfilename.sh" dev="xvdc" ino=3416830 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 tclass=file


type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1497770281.465:12508): arch=x86_64 syscall=execve success=no exit=EACCES a0=20d5650 a1=20d5730 a2=20d3c20 a3=7ffe9f4d7de0 items=0 ppid=10041 pid=10042 auid=4294967295 uid=995 gid=992 euid=995 suid=995 fsuid=995 egid=992 sgid=992 fsgid=992 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm=sh exe=/usr/bin/bash subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 key=(null)

Hash: sh,httpd_sys_script_t,httpd_sys_rw_content_t,file,execute
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**httpd_sys_rw_content_t** context will not work for executables. We need to set **httpd_sys_script_exec_t** context for that

```
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_script_exec_t  "/PATH_TO_FILE/myfilename.sh"
```

And then don't forget to run restorecon.

```
sudo restorecon -Rv /PATH_TO_FILE/
```

Comment: The "exec" within the context is a convention that means that the file with this context is an executable. It also means that when this executable is executed the process should run in a context with the same name removing the exec, in this case, httpd_sys_script_t.